# How can I get help with Stack Overflow addiction?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tips

My Stack Overflow addiction is beginning to hurt productivity.

Have you ever found yourself in this situation regarding some site?

Any advice on how to deal with the problem?

Comment: Should probably be in meta - I just quit cold turkey. Will power!

Comment: ... You even **tagged** this meta.

Comment: SO needs a button "Ban me please" and ComboBox with time intervals.

Comment: @Greg: I searched in stackoverflow, where the original question was posted. Looks like an opportunity to improve search results and mitigate posting to the wrong forum. :-)

Comment: @peterh-reinstatemonica please se: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/357107/the-existence-of-these-tags-reduce-my-efficiency-and-productivity/357151#357151

Comment: @Luuklag I strongly disagree both the question and the answer. Instead of eliminating the tags, they should be fixed. Using SE sites to increase personal productivity and efficiency should be a top important topic on the meta sites. Renaming them to "tips" is nearly so bad as deleting them.

Comment: @peterh-ReinstateMonica feel free to voice your opinion on the linked question, so others can vote on it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want you can flag one of your posts and ask a moderator to be banned for a period of time you specify; maybe this will help.

Answer (score 2):

I wish I could say more, but all I really have is that I've trained myself to always care about what I'm getting out of activities, so sooner or later, I end up realizing "Wait... this is a pointless grind" and losing interest... it's already happened with TV, video games, and most reading.

I'm currently evaluating whether my "10 points per day, minimum" goal on SO main is worth the time spent finding questions I can answer.