# How do I prevent a Stack Overflow addiction?

Tags: support, addon

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I keep from getting addicted to SO?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4004/how-can-i-keep-from-getting-addicted-to-so)

Looking up answers to questions on Stack Overflow  obviously is benefical for your employer, but it's very, very tempting, to keep asking questions, submitting answers to random questions just to to earn points, and get familiar with Stack Overflow  (and Stack Exchange).
I guess it's OK if you do that for questions/answers that are relevant for the company you work for.

So maybe a possibility is to determine whether it is relevant or not, and wait if you get home and still want to post/answer in your free time.

Comment: I can quite anytime I want! #denial

Comment: Many people believe there is nothing wrong with reading/answering random questions during your work hours because "you're learning". I think this is just a cheap excuse; you are paid to work not to learn by reading random questions which may or may not be useful in the future. You can learn in your free time.

Comment: Just start spending time in tags where low-quality questions are the norm.  You'll burn out in no time flat!

Comment: @Kop sounds very reasonable. reading answering questions should be done in free time if you are paid to deliver some working solution. I guess it may be a different story for consultants

Comment: @Charles which tags are that ?

Comment: @HCP, I burned out pretty bad in the PHP tag.  I understand that the Android tag is also pretty horrible.

Comment: I also feel this  really

Comment: Also: *[How addicted to Stack Overflow are you?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/11652/how-addicted-to-stack-overflow-are-you)* (deleted now, only visible to 10k+ reputation points users).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This question is a bit like Schrodinger's cat (or something like that).

The very act of answering proves that I'm not qualified to answer :)

Comment: Schrodinger's cat wasn't very good at answering questions.

Comment: The cat is/was either very good at answering questions or not very good at answering questions.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there is a way to determine the relevance of a post and wait to answer it in your free time. It makes use of a pretty powerful tool, the one located [between your ears](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_brain).

If you're afraid that you won't *remember* the question you wanted to check back in on by the time that you get home, you can mark the question as a *favorite* so that it will be added to a list in your profile:

[image: Marking a question as a "favorite"]

If you're just looking for general tips on managing your addiction, see these questions:

- [How can I keep from getting addicted to Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4004/how-can-i-keep-from-getting-addicted-to-so)
- [Addiction towards Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21037/addiction-towards-stackoverflow)
- https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21774/how-do-you-escape-an-addiction-to-stackoverflow-or-other-it-sites
- [How can I get help with Stack Overflow addiction?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69560/how-can-i-get-help-with-stack-overflow-addiction)
- [What is the expected time to get over SO addiction?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70868/what-is-the-expected-time-to-get-over-so-addiction)

Comment: Did you take that screenshot on April 1, or do you have a userscript that replicates the unicorns that I cannot find?

Comment: @adamjford: I only have MS Paint. The images of the unicorns are posted on here somewhere.

Comment: Damn. :)