# The existence of these tags reduce my [efficiency] and [productivity]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, meta, burninate-request

The [efficiency](/questions/tagged/efficiency) and [productivity](/questions/tagged/productivity) tags have no tag wiki, only 5 resp. 8 questions, and (especially the first one) are not used in a consistent way. I can see some point in focusing [productivity](/questions/tagged/productivity) on tips & tricks for using Stack Exchange, but we could also use [tips](/questions/tagged/tips) for that (that tag lacks guidance too, by the way). Thoughts?

Comment: [tag:efficiency] and [tag:productivity] might be of interest to those who like to talk about  [tag:cost] (another tag having a low number of questions and no tag excerpt)

Comment: Looking at the questions the first two seem a real rag-bag. I do not think any harm would come if they were eliminated. Many questions and answers provide tips so it is unclear what benefit having a small number tagged tips is so I would be inclined to eliminate that one too.

Comment: Proposed title: The existence of these tags come at a high [cost] and reduce my [efficiency] and [productivity]

Comment: Yeah, more tags can be burninated, but I don't want to risk the question becoming t̶o̶o̶ ̶b̶r̶o̶a̶d̶  needs more focus...

Comment: What about this title?: Overseeing the [cost] undermines our [efficiency] and [productivity] :D

Comment: Although this did not attract much interest nobody seems to have objected to my suggestion so shall I go ahead and do the re-tagging or would you like to do it?

Comment: @mdewey yeah, this has been up for a week now and we seem to have consensus. You may do the honors; personally, I would avoid doing too many edits at once, as not to flood the homepage with bumps; 3-4 per day should be fine.

Comment: Under way. I also put in a brief wiki about tips.

Comment: Having mdewey burniate can [lead to edit rejections](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/76041), whereas if Glorfindel did them they wouldn't go to review.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for all your efforts, these tags have been burninated!

[image: Burnination dragon]

Answer (score 4):

Just to update here.

I started work on re-tagging as there appeared to be a consensus that this was worthwhile. Subsequently a dissenting view appeared here and some of my edits were rejected from the Suggested Edits queue. I have therefore concluded that the consensus was more apparent than real and have stopped the re-tagging process. I have contributed wikis for the two tags which seem to cover most of the cases [tips](/questions/tagged/tips) and [cost](/questions/tagged/cost).

===== Original starts here =====

Let me make a concrete proposal for comment.

If there is a common theme behind the [efficiency](/questions/tagged/efficiency) and [productivity](/questions/tagged/productivity) tags it is people trying to improve their personal efficiency in using the site. They are not asking how to make the underlying software more efficient. It is therefore hard to see any difference between that and asking for tips about how to use the site so I would propose that all three sets of threads could be combined as [tips](/questions/tagged/tips). I think one of the questions asks about tooltips which is slightly different but tagging is never perfect.

Answer (score -9):

I strongly disagree both the question and the answer. Instead of eliminating the tags, they should be fixed. **Using SE sites to increase personal productivity and efficiency should be a top important topic on the metas.**

Renaming these tags to "tips" is nearly so bad as deleting them.